# MongoDB time difference then sum

Tags: mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Hello I'm getting the data for my time in and time out.

```
"record": [{
    "dateTime": {
        "$date": "2021-09-17T04:13:39.465Z"
    },
    "status": "time-in",
}, {
    "dateTime": {
        "$date": "2021-09-17T04:14:01.182Z"
    },
    "status": "time-out",
}],
```

I want to subtract the time difference from time out to time in

TIME OUT - TIME IN then sum to get the hours format.

Comment: Try using the Aggregation operator `$subtract` (it allows date subtraction) to return milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

In Mongo 5.0 you can use new function [$dateDiff](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateDiff/)

```
{
   $set: {
      diff: {
         $dateDiff: {
            startDate: { $first: "$record.dateTime" },
            endDate: { $last: "$record.dateTime" },
            unit: "hour"
         }
      }
   }
}
```